# How to stop recalculate value every time it's being finished?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a clock written with pure Javascript and CSS. Every time when new minute begins, my const which is responsible for rotating clocks hands is recalculated to first value (90deg). It causes problem because the clock's hand should rotate back to the first position from the end. 
I would like that my rotate value will not restart and always go on new minute\hour with current rotate value.

[Check my demo](http://codepen.io/Zharkov/pen/dNMJZM)

What I do?

**CSS**

```
.clock {
width: 20rem;
height: 20rem;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
background: #ffafbd;
/* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffafbd 0%, #ffc3a0 100%);
/* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffafbd 0%, #ffc3a0 100%);
/* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffafbd 0%, #ffc3a0 100%);
/* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffafbd', endColorstr='#ffc3a0', GradientType=0);
/* IE6-9 */
border-radius: 50%;
margin: 50px auto;
position: relative;
padding: 2rem;
}

.clock-face {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
transform: translateY(-3px);
/* account for the height of the clock hands */
}

.hand {
width: 50%;
height: 2px;
background: #4568dc;
/* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4568dc 0%, #b06ab3 100%);
/* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4568dc 0%, #b06ab3 100%);
/* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4568dc 0%, #b06ab3 100%);
/* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4568dc', endColorstr='#b06ab3', GradientType=0);
/* IE6-9 */
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: rotate(90deg);
transform-origin: 100%;
transition: transform .2s cubic-bezier(0, 2.48, 0.72, 0.66);
}

.hour-hand {
top: 45%;
left: 32.5%;
width: 35%;
transform-origin: 75%;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
const secondHand = document.querySelector(".second-hand");
const minutesHand = document.querySelector(".min-hand");
const hourHand = document.querySelector(".hour-hand");

function getDate() {
  const now = new Date();

  const seconds = now.getSeconds();
  const secondsRotate = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
  secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsRotate}deg)`;


  const minutes = now.getMinutes();
  const minutesRotate = ((minutes / 60) * 360) + 90;
  minutesHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minutesRotate}deg)`;

  const hours = now.getHours();
  const hoursRotate = ((hours / 12) * 360) + 90;
  hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hoursRotate}deg)`;

  console.log(hours);
}

setInterval(getDate, 1000);
```

Comment: `const secondsRotate = (((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90)%360;`

Comment: @Weedoze the same result

Comment: your problem is that you always animate your seconds about 3 degrees, but then suddenly you animate them -360 degrees. You have to remove the transformation for that -360 degrees change and it won't flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple disable the `secondHand.style.transition` when `secondHand` `transform` rotate degrees reach 90:

```
  const secondsRotate = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;

  if(secondsRotate == 90) {
    secondHand.style.transition = "none";
  } else {
    secondHand.style.transition = "transform .2s cubic-bezier(0, 2.48, 0.72, 0.66)";
  }

  secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsRotate}deg)`;
```

See it working here: http://codepen.io/clytras/pen/bgpvxB

Answer (score 0):

I have come across with this solution based on modifying the transition curve at a specific second:

```
function getDate() {
  const now = new Date();

  const seconds = now.getSeconds();
  secondsRotate = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
  if(seconds == 0) {
    secondHand.style.transitionDuration = "1s";
    secondHand.style.transitionTimingFunction = "cubic-bezier(0.545, 0.060, 0.360, 1.225)";
    secondsRotate = ((1 / 60) * 360) + 90;
  }
  else if(seconds == 1) {
    secondHand.style.transitionDuration = "0.2s";
    secondHand.style.transitionTimingFunction = "cubic-bezier(0, 2.48, 0.72, 0.66)";
  }
  secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsRotate}deg)`;


  const minutes = now.getMinutes();
  const minutesRotate = ((minutes / 60) * 360) + 90;
  minutesHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minutesRotate}deg)`;

  const hours = now.getHours();
  const hoursRotate = ((hours / 12) * 360) + 90;
  hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hoursRotate}deg)`;

  console.log(minutesRotate);
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bgpvoe